# "Saving results as" from SQL results in a couple of unusual rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, export

I have 960 rows of data in my table which **appears** to be normal looking.  But, when I "Save Results As" from the query results window and save to a, for example, an XLSX file, I get a couple of weird, inserted extra rows that's not consistent with the other rows of data.  I searched for newline, carriage return characters (and the data didn't have any).  My thought was maybe there's something in the data itself that was causing a new row to be created.  Any ideas?

Here's my result set from the query results window (notice row 689):

[image]

When I "Save Results As" by right clicking the result set from the query results window and save as either XLSX, CSV, TXT - here's what I get (again, notice row 689):

[image]

Comment: maybe an issure with `crlf` try replacing `char(13)+char(10)` in the column(s)

Comment: SQL Server will split any element over 5000 characters into multiple rows. Try opening the raw XML or CSV in Notepad, and see if there are any really long rows.

Comment: on the sql editor tab, click on "Result to File" or "Result to text" and copy from there and see if that helps.

Comment: Also use Import wizard and import all columns as text while pasting in excel

Comment: @TI - if you make your comment an answer I'll mark it as the answer.  I found/replaced all CHAR(10) which resolved the issue.

Comment: notice 686 is different too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with `crlf`try replacing `char(13)+char(10)` in the column(s)

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 = REPLACE(REPLACE(col3, CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), '')
FROM tbl
```

Comment: The problem was resolved by finding/replacing all CHAR(10) with an empty string.  Thanks!!